# javascript - check if array object contains a array by values

Tags: javascript, arrays

trying to check if a value of array present on a base array and return as string-

base array:

```
const filters = {
    "name: "location",
    "data" : [
        "dana-point",
        "canada-so"
    ]
}

const posts = [
    {
        "date": "09 February 2022",
        "title": "There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available",
        "locations": [
            "dana-point",
            "new-york"
        ],
        "url": "/news/many-variations",
    },
    {
        // so may items
    },
]
```

I wanted to return all post which matched with filter data object with at least one value match like - on above example it will retrun first post as its match the location, dana-point.

let filteredPosts = posts.filter(item => checks.includes(item[checks.data])));

it's not working

Comment: Are you saying the check is not always for the `locations` field of `posts`? The example makes that seem a bit difficult, as the name of `checks` is singular "location", while the field on `posts` is plural "locations". If the specified name of `checks` doesn't even match that of the `posts`, there's going to be a lot of hardcoding.

Comment: In your filter predicate you need to iterate through `item.locations` and do `checks.data.includes` for each until it matches.

Comment: @YannickK correct, its a dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```js
const checks = [
  {
    name: "locations",
    data: ["dana-point", "canada-so"]
  }
];

const posts = [
  {
    date: "09 February 2022",
    title: "There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available",
    locations: ["dana-point", "new-york"],
    url: "/news/many-variations"
  }
];

const filtered = posts.filter((post) =>
  checks.every((check) =>
    post[check.name].some((data) => check.data.includes(data))
  )
);
```

Comment: where do those `every` and `some` come from?

Comment: they are functions of arrays in Javascript @tromgy

Comment: Ah, I see, you made `checks` an array.  `checks` in the question was not an array.

Comment: the only thing that changes if its not an array is that you can remove the first every